# C# not catching exceptions in code, or with debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, emgucv

I'm learning how to use Emgu, and am having issues with VS2015 not breaking on it's exceptions, as well as it's exceptions not being caught by try/catch blocks. The exception notification in visual studio will flash for a second, then the program exits.

**My code:**

```
using System;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.Util;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;

namespace OpenCV1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\receipt-1.jpg"))
                {
                    float scale = (float)500 / (float)image.Height;
                    var resized = image.Resize(scale, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Inter.Nearest);
                    var grey = image.Convert<Gray, byte>();
                    grey = grey.SmoothGaussian(5, 5, 1, 1);
                    var edged = grey.Canny(25, 100);

                    //ImageViewer.Show(edged, "edged");

                    VectorOfVectorOfPointF contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPointF();
                    Mat hierarchy = null;
                    CvInvoke.FindContours(edged.Copy(), contours, hierarchy, RetrType.List, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My VS2015 Exception Settings:**

[image]

**Screenshot of Exception** (this flashes almost too fast to see before closing):

[image]

Why can I not catch these exceptions, and why will visual studio not break on them? It still shows the exception message, but it almost instantly closes.

Comment: When i have seen this behavior before it is because a exception happens in unmanaged code called by the debugger. Try keeping all "Watch" or "Locals" windows closed so you don't have any way to see the content of any variables, then see if the error stays up.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Closed them, same deal

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the caught exception type from the catch block. Just have it as follows:

```
try
{
   // logic here...
}
catch
{
    // handler
}
```

This should catch whatever hasn't been caught by the "Exception" specific handler. Or just add an additional catch block below the existing one and see whether that one catches it.

Comment: Still does not catch it, even if it did though, I only need to catch it so I can see what the actual exception is while learning.

Comment: Can you share a test project somewhere - would be interesting to see what's going on.

Comment: Another thought (probably not the case though): VS debugger by default would handle the exception first, before the execution will get to the handler. If you press "Continue" on the first exception break - it should just continue execution (assuming there are handlers for it).

Comment: I'll upload the project and comment. As for continuing, there is no way to continue as the program closes almost instantly, VS does not break on the exception for more than 1/10th of a second or so before closing the program, it took me many tries to get the screenshot of the exception.

Comment: I'm really curious to look into that. Looking forward for your post with share location.

Comment: Here is a zip with the project http://douglasgaskell.com/wp-content/uploads/OpenCV1.zip

Comment: Well, the handler works for me just fine - not sure how to send you the screenshot. Here are the exception details:
Emgu.CV.Util.CvException: OpenCV: mtype == type0 || (CV_MAT_CN(mtype) == CV_MAT_CN(type0) && ((1 << type0) & fixedDepthMask) != 0)
   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.CvErrorHandler(Int32 status, IntPtr funcName, IntPtr errMsg, IntPtr fileName, Int32 line, IntPtr userData)
   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cveFindContours(IntPtr image, IntPtr contours, IntPtr hierarchy, RetrType mode, ChainApproxMethod method, Point& offset)...

Comment: @DouglasGaskell, looks like you have an issue with VS. What version do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using CvException rather than Exception

Doug

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after migrating my application from EmguCV 2.4.2 to 3.2.0. After loosing some hair I found a Solution that worked for me.

Go to

Tools --> Options --> Debugging --> General

and **enable** the option **Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators**

[image]

According to VS2015 doc this will do the following: The debugger will use the Visual Studio 2013 C#/VB expression evaluators instead of the Visual Studio 2015 Roslyn-based expression evaluators.

For me enabling this option solved the Problem. Exception dialogs are now shown and the debugging process isn't killed any more.